# Derivation of Cubed-Inverse Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a Gaussian distributed random variable. For physical reasons, I'm interested here in the PDF of a cubic-inversed Gaussian distribution, so:

$Y \to 1/X^3$

I'm certain about the Inversed Gaussian Distribution/Wald Distribution, but I don't have a clue, how I can derive the PDF for my case.
Does a solution exist for this problem?

Thank you in advance!
I'm appreciating any help and hints!

Comment: Just apply the [change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)

Comment: It is a simple change of variable: you should get a two peaked density (symmetric about $0$ if the the original Gaussian distribution was).  This is not particularly related to the Wald distribution, misleadingly called *inverse Gaussian*

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly, what I have been looking for! :)